# InstantiationException, newInstance failed: no <init>, while there is only default constructor in Activity

Tags: android, instantiationexception

We received stack trace of InstantiationException while creating instance of Activity. 
Log has `newInstance failed: no <init>()` message

The situation is quite clear: VM can't find default parameterless constructor. This is explained in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120699/newinstance-failed-no-init)

As my research shown people usually receive this when they add parameters to constructors of their Activities, which definitely is bad. But this is not our case - we always have access to default constructor. 
Another reason of that exception could be another exception while initializing some member(initialiation is run in default constructor, right?) - but again we don't do that. All members are initialized in onCreate() method.

Some details(names changed):
activity is added to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest
    package="app.name"
    ....>
    ....
    <activity
        android:name="app.name.activity.OurActivity"
        android:label="@string/NAME">
    </activity>
```

Now the way that we create the intent may look strange, but it works in every case:

```
Context packageContext = layoutInflater.getContext().createPackageContext("app.name", 0);
Intent intent = new Intent(packageContext, OurActivity.class);
...startActivity(intent);
```

I would think that this could be a problem, but:
1) this works fine for months
2) same client got same exception in another activity which is start using activity as a context;

I can't reproduce the exception to understand/fix it. But somehow one of our clients got it. He has Droid ERIS(Verizon) device

Any thoughts? Is there any case I don't know about when VM will not find the default constructor?

Comment: Why are you starting an activity like that?

Comment: @Falmarri That was obviously a mistake (lack of experience I think). We don't do it anymore of course. The more important is that this way it also works so that none has any problems. I just don't believe it is source of problem