# New instance of class based on argument

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a function that takes one of many classes that extends `Foo`, and return a new instance of that object in its Class, not a new instance of `Foo`.

I'm sure this is a common issue. Is there any good examples out there?

I have never used a class as an input parameter, only members of a class. Based on what I have searched for, this should be possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you passing a `Class` object as the parameter, or in instance of a subclass of `Foo`?

The solution is almost the same in either case, you use the [newInstance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) method on the Class object.

```
/**
 * Return a new subclass of the Foo class.
 */
public Foo fooFactory(Class<? extends Foo> c)
{
    Foo instance = null;
    try {
        instance = c.newInstance();
    }
    catch (InstantiationException e) {
        // ...
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // ...
    }
    return instance; // which might be null if exception occurred,
                     // or you might want to throw your own exception
}
```

If you need constructor args you can use the Class [getConstructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29) method and from there the Constructor [newInstance(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Object...%29) method.

Comment: Thanks mate. ... Seems to be working now. For other reading, After this I got one of the exceptions and solved with this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120699/newinstance-failed-no-init

Answer (score 1):

Your function could be like this

```
public class NewInstanceTest {
    public static Object getNewInstance(Foo fooObject){
        java.lang.Class fooObjectClass = fooObject.getClass();
        try {
            return fooObjectClass.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
 }
 public static void main(java.lang.String[] args){
        // This prints Foo
        java.lang.System.out.println(getNewInstance(new Foo()).getClass().getName());
        // This prints Foo1
        java.lang.System.out.println(getNewInstance(new Foo1()).getClass().getName());
 }
}
class Foo{
}
class Foo1 extends Foo{
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Abstract Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java's reflection here.

If you want to get a `Class` by just its classname, you use `Class.forName`:

```
Class type = Class.forName('package.SomeClass');
```

You can check if this class is `Foo` or a subclass of it:

```
boolean isFoo = type.isAssignableFrom(Foo.class);
```

You can then create a new instance very easily (assuming the constructor takes no arguments):

```
Object instance = type.newInstance();
```