# "newInstance failed: no <init>()" when starting another Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

This app was working, and now it isn't, and I can't see why. The exception happens on

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_todo);
```

I looked at all the other answers to similar questions that I could find, and none of them solved my problem.

Here's the main activity:

```
public class TodoActivity extends Activity  {

    ...

    lvItems.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long rowId) {
        Intent i = new Intent(TodoActivity.this, EditItemActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(EDIT_ITEM_NAME,items.get(position));
        i.putExtra(EDIT_ITEM_POSITION, position);

        // pass the due date as a long 
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date d = c.getTime();
        i.putExtra(DUE_DATE, d.getTime() );
        startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);

        return;
    }
```

Here's the EditItemActivity:

```
public class EditItemActivity extends FragmentActivity 
{

    ...

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String itemName;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_item);

        ...
```

I changed it to extend `FragmentActivity` so I could start a `Fragment` after a checkbox is clicked. But I changed it *back* to `Activity` as a test, and it still crashes.

Can anyone please tell me what's going on? And how to fix it?

Comment: have you registered `EditItemActivity` Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` ?

Comment: Have you added a constructor taking arguments to `EditItemActivity`? Activities should only have the implicit no-args constructor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [newInstance failed: no <init>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120699/newinstance-failed-no-init)

Comment: please move String itemName; line after super and setContentView line in onCreate().